# QGIS DTM loading error

Tags: qgis, dem, os-opendata

I have downloaded a full set of text DTM's for Northern Ireland from OSNI Open Data, but when I load them into QGIS, some of them do not appear. When I try to load the missing files, I get an error message:

"Ungridded dataset: At line 38676, too many stepY values" (this is from one of the files, so the line number may differ for each offending file).

The URL to download one of the sets is:
https://opendatani.blob.core.windows.net/lpsopendata/10M-DTM-Sheets1-50.zip

In this dataset, you will find that 'sheets' 2, 6 and 16 are the problem files.

Is anyone able to shed any light on what may be causing the problem?

Comment: I can load them here in QGIS 3.0. Numbers 2 and 6 are on the coast and 16 has a couple of dozen points off of its main area of coverage but still loads. How are you adding the files?

Comment: I imported them through the Add Raster Layer tool.